# See full redirect path and HTTP status code (in Chrome)

Tags: redirect, google-chrome-devtools, http-status-codes

[image: Chrome developer tools display redirect path and HTTP status code]
.

In Chrome's developer tools, under the "Network" tab, I can see redirect paths and HTTP status code if I check "Preserve log". See image above, where you can see the domain **ap.no** redirect to
**www.aftenposten.no** and returning a status code **301**.

My problem is that it doesn't work for all sites. Are there situations where Chrome will not be able to know that a redirect has happened?

One example is amazon.com, which redirects to www.amazon.com, but I cannot see the redirect in Chrome's developer tools.

Is there another way to see the redirect info in these cases where Chrome doesn't seem to pick it up?

Comment: I can't replicate it on Amazon, it shows up as expected.

Comment: Thanks for testing. I have tried disabling all extensions and using an incognito window, but I still cannot get the redirect status code for amazon.com→www.amazon.com. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that I have visited the site before. I tried amazon.de→www.amazon.de, and there I could see the status code.

The problem is that I (obviously) want to test my own sites, which I have visited many times before, so I need to figure out how to disable this caching or whatever it is.

Comment: After I cleared all browsing data, I am now able to see the redirect status code 301 from amazon.com → www.amazon.com. It seems to work every time I try now, and at least I have a workaround if it should start happening again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these methods to get around the issue (in order of complexity):

1. Use an incognito window when you load the page.
2. Use the extension "Cache Killer" to disable caching of data.
3. If all else fails, clear all browsing data from Chrome.

In this instance, only clearing browsing data helped, but I regularly use Cache Killer and incognito window when I am testing my own websites.